# Snap package daemons won't start on fresh Ubuntu Server install

Tags: server, 18.04, snap, policykit

a couple of days ago I installed Ubuntu Server 18.04.
Snap packages were a large reason for this, however snap package daemons won't start.
So far I've tried NextCloud, PlexMediaServer and RocketChat-Server packages with no success.

Log output is not that helpful. 
For example:
    sudo snap logs nextcloud
Gives:

```
snap.nextcloud.apache.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2019-01-22T20:46:16Z systemd[1]: snap.nextcloud.apache.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
2019-01-22T20:46:16Z systemd[1]: snap.nextcloud.apache.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 46.
2019-01-22T20:46:16Z systemd[1]: Stopped Service for snap application nextcloud.apache.
2019-01-22T20:46:16Z systemd[1]: Started Service for snap application nextcloud.apache.
2019-01-22T20:46:16Z nextcloud.apache[6362]: Making sure nextcloud is setup...
2019-01-22T20:46:17Z nextcloud.apache[6362]: Nextcloud is not installed - only a limited number of commands are available
2019-01-22T20:46:17Z nextcloud.apache[6362]:                                                                    
2019-01-22T20:46:17Z nextcloud.apache[6362]:   There are no commands defined in the "config:system" namespace.
2019-01-22T20:46:17Z nextcloud.apache[6362]:
```

Looking at the logs for snapd, the following stands out:

```
 Started Snappy daemon.
Jan 21 20:49:56 serveme snapd[8702]: daemon.go:193: polkit error: Authorization requires interaction
Jan 22 01:53:12 serveme snapd[8702]: storehelpers.go:443: cannot refresh: snap has no updates availa
```

Though it's unclear if this is related.
Does anyone have any ideas where to start? Since this is a fresh install it's a bit annoying to run into this first thing and any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was able to coax life out of my snaps by running:

```
sudo snap refresh core --beta
```

This allowed nextcloud snap to start, plexmediaserver still has problems but this no longer seems to be a general snap problem.